# Generating a mock object filled with arbitrary values

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm new to java and have to test classes.

I need a mock object for a very complicated class, where some properties are objects, which in turn have other objects so forth, so for me to manually generate a mock object is a lot of work to do.

I was wondering if there is a way to generate that mock object automatically, but not just that, also if is possible to automatically fill all the properties of that object with some arbitrary values.

Could somebody help me on this, please?

I'm going to put an example here, to be sure I made myself clear...

```
class A {
int a;
B b;
C c;
}

class B {
int x;
C k;
}

class C {
String x;
int x;
}
```

And I want to mock an object of the A class.

I want that mockA object to have values for all possible fields, for example for the x String from the B class also...

Comment: Just to be clear, you want your mock object to return other mock objects?

Comment: Yes, I want a final object filled with arbitrary values for all the properties, including the nested object ones and the nested object in these objects and so on, until it reaches the primitive types properties if you know what I mean, my english is pretty poor also, not just my java knowledge...

Comment: Why do you want to have values for the fields?  Surely what matters is what happens when you call the mock's methods?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/) and [RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) option might be what you're looking for. What's more, mockito seems often to return sensible values by default.

Example usage from the linked documentation, for quick reference:

```
Foo mock = mock(Foo.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

// note that we're stubbing a chain of methods here: getBar().getName()
when(mock.getBar().getName()).thenReturn("deep");

// note that we're chaining method calls: getBar().getName()
assertEquals("deep", mock.getBar().getName());
```

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it, hope it works and I'll be back with updates. Thank you.

Comment: So, I did a test and it seems that Mockito cannot mock final classes?!? Nor primitive types. At least is what I'm getting as an error message. What to do? Because I need to mock a final class.

Comment: I tested on a non-final class also, it works, but all the fields are null, so I would have done that in a blink manually. There is a way to automatically fill these values, as I said in the question? I used the RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS example with my class.

Comment: Yeah, mocking final classes requires heavier machinery. Mockito usually dismisses such problems, saying the design is to blame. For this, look at Powermock: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/. It can mock pretty much everything: final classes, statics, `new` calls etc. I've never heard of mocking field access, though. Yet another reason to use getters. As for mocking primitives... they don't have behaviour, what would you like to achieve?

Comment: I need that mock to test a method in a class (it's about simulating a result of a query) and I will spend one full day of work just filling the fields of that mock because its a huge class. Thank you for your help though.

Comment: I used RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS but getting a null pointer exception on this.